# maven test stuck

Tags: testing, maven

When I try to do maven test or install on my own computer, it works very well.
Then when I move the whole project to qa machine, it gets stuck at testing forever.
In the test file, It gets stuck at a point where a new instance of a class.
like **MyClass object = new MyClass();**

I tried to run the test in the main thread, it still gets stuck.
Could someone give me some suggestion about what's happening?

Also, how to set breakpoint from command line to do maven debug.

Thank you

Comment: Run mvn test -X on your QA machine and post the stack trace would help others find your problem.

Comment: you can use mvnDebug and remote debugger in eclipse for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Attach to the running process using `jconsole` and use the threads tab to see where it's stuck.